# Custom E-Mail Event for Sharepoint Upon InfoPath Form Submit

Tags: sharepoint, email, sharepoint-2007, infopath

A customer wants an e-mail notification sent to a select group of people when a new InfoPath form is submitted to a particular Document Library on their SharePoint 2007 setup.

Easy, right? Use a custom set of rules for an e-mail submission in InfoPath, plop in the addresses, use a fancy equation to construct a useful e-mail subject line... and done. Worked like a charm. Problem solved in just a few minutes...

However, the customer doesn't want the whole form e-mailed out or even attached to the e-mail. They only want a few select fields from the form in a very simple message.

I've tried writing an `ItemAdded` event handler from the `SPItemEventReceiver` base class, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Yes, I added the event handler to the GAC and created a Feature.xml and Elements.xml to register the event handler with SharePoint. But, I'm not sure if this is even the right event to customize. Is an item in a Document Library the same as an item in a List?

Has anyone had luck doing a similar e-mail notification event? Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm attempting? Perhaps there's a way to do this easily through the SharePoint interface or edit the contents of the e-mail submission rule to be a simplified version of the form?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a very simple SharePoint Designer workflow that is triggered when the form is uploaded. From there you [send an email and include content of the (exported) columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx) in an email body.

Comment: This seems to be the solution I was looking for. I was just lacking the right development software to do it. Now, I just need to get the e-mail communicating properly. Thanks for the helpful insight!