# SharePoint 2007 Workflow Doesn't Trigger On InfoPath Form Submit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330269).

This is what I expect to happen:

1. User navigates to Document Library
2. User clicks New
3. InfoPath form opens
4. User fills in data
5. User clicks Submit
6. Form submitted to Document Library
7. Workflow triggered by New Item sends stripped-down form data as e-mail
8. Everyone is happy

The problem is, I never reach Step #8 because the Workflow does not trigger. I have all three options selected for triggering the Workflow - Manual, New Item, Updated Item. The Manual trigger works great on items in the Document Library and the Workflow does exactly what it needs to do, but the other two triggers never seem to fire.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance running as the system account? Have a look at [this question and answer on sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/workflow-not-triggering-on-new-item-in-e-mail-enabled-list) (where you really want to move all your SharePoint questions to)

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks! I really wish this would have been a more obvious "feature", though. I've actually had the workflow working since last week, but didn't know because the System Account wasn't triggering it when I was testing...